# Merge the [refit] tag into [refind]?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are currently 62 questions tagged [refit], and 58 tagged [refind].

[rEFIt](http://refit.sourceforge.net) was a boot manager that made booting Linux on a Mac painless. It seems to have been **superseded** by [rEFInd](https://rodsbooks.com/refind/), which is still in active development.

Should we merge the [refit] tag into [refind]?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this makes for a good merge. rEFIt and rEFInd are two different software, with the latter being a fork of the former, not just another release of the original software. It is unclear that question that apply to rEFIt would automatically apply to rEFInd and vice versa, and such should be kept distinct if this is the case.

In the same way old versions of macOS are superseded with newer versions and we want to encourage new users to use the latest version of macOS, that doesn't mean we invalidate all High Sierra questions making them Mojave questions by merging [high-sierra](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/high-sierra) into [mojave](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mojave)!

Comment: Interesting, two completely different opinions! (: Is rEFIt still active anymore, though? Is there any circumstance in which you might want to use it over rEFInd? If not, why not just redirect people to rEFInd instead?

Comment: @Silver It's great to redirect new people to use rEFInd, but that doesn't mean retroactively making all questions on the site currently asking about rEFIt now about rEFInd, potentially invalidating existing answers on the site.

Comment: Hm, that is a very good point. Should we suggest on the rEFIt tag to use rEFInd instead, perhaps?

Comment: @Silver Such a message could go in the tag wiki excerpt

Answer (score -2):

Yes. That makes an excellent merge. Would you be willing to proof read the wiki edit I make for accuracy?

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/tags/refind/info

I moved the old excerpt into the wiki tag body and then tried to fix the excerpt to indicate both tools belong to that tag. The distinction of what’s a boot manager and which one hasn’t been maintained since 2013 need to be edited in to the body for sure.

Comment: I'd be happy to proofread the tag wiki edit! (After this all gets decided, of course.)

Comment: Huh, did they get merged already? I was going to edit the [rEFIt] description to point users to rEFInd, but this works too. Maybe I should edit back in "this tag should be used for both". (: